# MySql Connector C++ ResultSet buffered

Tags: c++, buffer, database-performance, mysql-connector

I am currently working on the performance of a database (frontend) in C++ with the MySqlConnector-library.
The library has own datatypes/classes like the `sql::ResultSet`.

After you send a `SELECT`-statement to the database you receive a `sql::ResultSet*` (pointer) which I put into a sharedpointer: `typedef boost::shared_ptr<sql::ResultSet> ResultPtr`

I use this pointer multiple times in different modules. All need the result of this operation. You can call operations like `myResultPtr->getMetaData()->getColumnName(columnindex)`

**My question:**
Are operations like above buffered or does the MySqlConnector-library always ask the database (via connection) for metadata? Should i build a buffer for this or is the ResultSet (especially the metadata) buffered?

Answer (score 1):

In the docs I found a line, that all data is buffered. I measured the time on huge Datasets and found out, that the MetaData have to be buffered, too.

You **don't** need to build a buffer for the MySqlConnector-library.